# About limit points of open sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now.

Given a compact Hausdorff space $X$, regular open subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ (the interior of their closure is themselves), does this hold?

$d(A) \subseteq B$ implies $d(X - Cl(B)) \subseteq X - Cl(A)$

Thank you

Comment: There appears to be something missing in your Q. What relation is there between A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is yes, and I do not think you need the space to be compact.

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $d(A) \subseteq B$ but there is some point $p\in d(X \setminus cl(B))$ with $p\in cl(A)$.

Then there is some $C\subseteq (X\setminus cl(B))$ such that $p\in(cl(C)\setminus C)$.

Note that $p\not\in B$. Indeed, if $p\in B$ then since $p\in cl(C)$ and $B$ is a neighborhood of $p$ it follows that $C\cap B\not=\emptyset$ contradicting that $C\cap cl(B)=\emptyset$.

This $p\not\in B$, which implies $p\not\in d(A)$. But $p\in cl(A)$, hence 
$p\in A$. But since $A$ is open and $p\in cl(C)$ it follows that 
$p\in cl(A\cap C)$, and hence $p\in d(A)$, a contradiction which completes the proof.

I did not use that $X$ is compact, and that $A$ and $B$ are regular open (though I did use that they are open). Do you have examples showing that these additional conditions are necessary?